# Ajax Call Success Now Working - Passing JSON Object [String]

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to develop some validation within my application to check if a **Function Name** all ready exists within the database. Rather than using SQL I wanted to use ajax to pass this data through.

Unfortunately when trying to pass this **JSON (String) Object**, the `response` is never being passed `success: function (response)` and I am getting an error message.

I was hoping for some advise as to why this might be occurring as I believe my code is within the correct format to complete successfully.

I have tried changing the datatype to `text` and have also included    `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8` but this has not helped solve the issue.

```
function AllowedFunction(FunctionName) {
    var result = "None";        
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FunAllowed")',
        type: "POST",            
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { FunctionName: FunctionName },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.length > 0)
            {
                result = "True";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "False";
            }              
            }            
    });
    return result;
}



    // VAL: Function Name Allowed
    public JsonResult FunAllowed(string FunctionName)
    {            
        var records = db.Functions.Where(x => x.FunctionName == FunctionName).ToList();
        string result = "False";

        if (records.Count > 0)
            result = "True";

        return Json(records, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

ReferenceError: response is not defined at eval (eval at AllowedFunction (http://localhost:52613/Functions/Create:50:9), :1:1)
1.  message: "response is not defined"
2.  stack: "ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: Verify the response with fiddler or the browser debugging tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably because your `FunAllowed` function is expecting a `string`, but you're passing an `object` with a *property* named `FunctionName` which is a `string`.

I  think if you did this it might work without changing your JS code:

```
class FunAllowedinput
{
    public string FunctionName{get;set;}
}
public JsonResult FunAllowed(FunAllowedInput input)
{            
    var records = db.Functions.Where(x => x.FunctionName == input.FunctionName).ToList();
    string result = "False";

    if (records.Count > 0)
        result = "True";

    return Json(records, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hello GPW, Thank you for your above comments however the same issue is occurring whereby the response is not defined. Do you have any other advice?